# Hint for show that $\sin AOB \sin COD + \sin AOC \sin DOB + \sin AOD \sin BOC = 0$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I need a hint for proof of:

If $OA, OB, OC, OD$ any four lines meeting in a point $O$, show that 
$$\sin AOB \sin COD + \sin AOC \sin DOB + \sin AOD \sin BOC = 0$$

I'm thinking of applying several times the theorem of generalized bisector

Comment: Are the angles oriented? I.e. $\sin(DOB)=-\sin(BOD)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\widehat{AOB}=\alpha$, $\widehat{BOC}=\beta$, $\widehat{COD}=\gamma$, $\widehat{DOA}=\delta$.

Then $\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta=2\pi$, so, by eliminating $\delta$ and using Briggs' formulas:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} &&2\cdot[ \sin(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)-\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin(\beta+\gamma)-\sin(\delta)\sin(\beta)]\\&=&2\cdot[\sin(\alpha)\sin(\gamma)-\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin(\beta+\gamma)+\sin(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)\sin(\beta)]\\&=&\cos(\alpha-\gamma)-\cos(\alpha+\gamma)-\cos(\alpha-\gamma)+\cos(\alpha+2\beta+\gamma)+\cos(\alpha+\gamma)-\cos(\alpha+2\beta+\gamma)\\&=&\color{red}{0}.\end{eqnarray*} $$

Comment: Would you please mention what the original Briggs' formulas are or where I can find them on the internet? Never heard of them ..

Comment: @HandeBruijn: I was just referring to: $$\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)=\frac{1}{2}\left[\cos(\alpha-\beta)-\cos(\alpha+\beta)\right].$$